# How to parse the content with a specific column in a csv file on bash

Tags: bash, csv, multiple-columns

I'm trying to parse a csv file line by line and the format of it is something like this:

```
"name","content1,with commas as you see", "content2, also may contain commas", "..."
...
...
```

I want to get the content on specific column,without quotes. eg: the 1st column and the 3rd one. So the expected content should be:

```
name  (if get column 1)
content2, also may contain commas   (if get column 3)
```

I tried to use awk but it didn't work. Also I tried:

```
while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3 col4; 
do 
echo "got ${col1}|${col3}"; 
done < file
```

But it contains the quotes "", and the content of col3 is wrong, which mixed the comma inside each column. How should I split such formats which contain commas in each column then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of such complexities as these, it's probably much easier if you use an actual CSV parser like [`csvtool`](https://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/csv/) for this:

```
$ csvtool col 3 - <<< '"name","content1,with commas as you see", "content2, also may contain commas", "..."'
"content2, also may contain commas"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have `GNU awk` then `FPAT` will come to your rescue.

```
gawk '{print $1,$3}' FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" my.csv
```

In `awk` we normally use `FS` which defines what a field is not, instead of what a field is. In this particular case, we really want to define the fields by what they are and `FPAT` allows us to do exactly that.

Comment: hmm, seems like it doesn't work either, the column still confused with the comma inside the content. And I may need to process them line by line.

Comment: You will need `GNU awk` version 4 or later.